# How to park a vehicle in a random parking space?

Tags: sumo

I was wondering how to park a vehicle in a random parking spot. As can be seen from the attached figure, all vehicles park sequentially.

I have already defined all parking areas in the *.net.xml file and the vehicles that should park in the *.rou.xml file.

I am using SUMO 1.2.0.

[Parking Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJNd3.png)

Comment: To solve, I thought of adding in a lane more than one parking area. Would it be the best solution?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is it just for a more natural visualization?

Comment: I will use parked vehicles to forward packages for moving vehicles. In the real world, it is common to have vehicles parked in non-sequential parking spaces. Having vehicles parked like that would be close to reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot assign a specific spot in a parking area, so yes defining multiple areas is probably the best option.